# Laradock (docker) keeps throwing http error 500

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

No matter what I try, I keep getting HTTP error code 500 when I visit my docker-machine ip.

I am running laradock through Docker tool box (OS: Windows 10) and have a default VM running. I have setup laradock as per the instructions in the video.

I have successfully mounted the folder that I need into the VM and have changed docker-compose.yml according to the location of my code in the VM:

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

> version: '2'
>
> services:
>
> #### Nginx Server Container
>
> ```
> nginx:
>     build: ./nginx
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_source
>     volumes:
>         - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
>     ports:
>         - "80:80"
>         - "443:443"
>     links:
>         - php-fpm
> ```
>
> #### PHP-FPM Container
>
> ```
> php-fpm:
>     build:
>         context: ./php-fpm
>         dockerfile: Dockerfile-70
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_source
>     expose:
>         - "9000"
>     links:
>         - workspace
> ```
>
> #### MySQL Container
>
> ```
> mysql:
>     build: ./mysql
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
>     ports:
>         - "3306:3306"
>     environment:
>         MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
>         MYSQL_USER: homestead
>         MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
>         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
> ```
>
> #### PostgreSQL Container
>
> ```
> postgres:
>     build: ./postgres
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
>     ports:
>         - "5432:5432"
>     environment:
>         POSTGRES_DB: homestead
>         POSTGRES_USER: homestead
>         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
> ```
>
> #### MariaDB Container
>
> ```
> mariadb:
>     build: ./mariadb
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
>     ports:
>         - "3306:3306"
>     environment:
>         MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
>         MYSQL_USER: homestead
>         MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
>         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
> ```
>
> #### Neo4j Container
>
> ```
> neo4j:
>     build: ./neo4j
>     ports:
>         - "7474:7474"
>         - "1337:1337"
>     environment:
>         - NEO4J_AUTH=homestead:secret
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
> ```
>
> #### MongoDB Container
>
> ```
> mongo:
>     build: ./mongo
>     ports:
>         - "27017:27017"
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
> ```
>
> #### Redis Container
>
> ```
> redis:
>     build: ./redis
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
>     ports:
>         - "6379:6379"
> ```
>
> #### Memcached Container
>
> ```
> memcached:
>     build: ./memcached
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_data
>     ports:
>         - "11211:11211"
>     links:
>         - php-fpm
> ```
>
> #### Beanstalkd Container
>
> ```
> beanstalkd:
>     build: ./beanstalkd
>     ports:
>         - "11300:11300"
>     privileged: true
>     links:
>         - php-fpm
> ```
>
> #### Beanstalkd Console Container
>
> ```
> beanstalkd-console:
>     build: ./beanstalkd-console
>     ports:
>         - "2080:2080"
>     links:
>         - beanstalkd
> ```
>
> #### Workspace Utilities Container
>
> ```
> workspace:
>     build:
>         context: ./workspace
>         args:
>             - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=false
>     volumes_from:
>         - volumes_source
>     tty: true
> ```
>
> #### Laravel Application Code Container
>
> ```
> volumes_source:
>     build: ./volumes/application
>     volumes:
>         - /c/Users/pomodoro.xyz/code:/var/www/laravel
> ```
>
> #### Databases Data Container
>
> ```
> volumes_data:
>     build: ./volumes/data
>     volumes:
>         - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
>         - /var/lib/postgres:/var/lib/postgres
>         - /var/lib/mariadb:/var/lib/mariadb
>         - /var/lib/memcached:/var/lib/memcached
>         - /var/lib/redis:/data
>         - /var/lib/neo4j:/var/lib/neo4j/data
>         - /var/lib/mongo:/data/db
> ```
>
> #### Add more Containers below

When I log into the workspace and change files, they are reflected into the host machine, so I am good on that front.

Here is my folder structure in my work container (just as per the video):

```
root@d463d55e545b:/var/www/laravel# ls -l
total 30
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 4096 Jul 20 19:58 app
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 1646 Jul 20 19:58 artisan
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff    0 Jul 20 19:58 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 1272 Jul 20 19:58 composer.json
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 4096 Jul 20 19:58 config
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 4096 Jul 20 19:58 database
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff  503 Jul 20 19:58 gulpfile.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff   12 Jul 21 15:13 index.html
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 4096 Jul 23 09:24 laradock
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff  212 Jul 20 19:58 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 1026 Jul 20 19:58 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 4096 Jul 23 10:39 public
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 1918 Jul 20 19:58 readme.md
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff    0 Jul 20 19:58 resources
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff  567 Jul 20 19:58 server.php
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff    0 Jul 20 19:58 storage
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff    0 Jul 20 19:58 tests
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff    0 Jul 20 19:59 vendor
```

All nginx.conf files etc are being loaded into the container as I can see from docker exec -it into my nginx container.

For reference, here is my laravel.conf

> server {
>       listen 80 default_server;
>       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
>
> ```
> root /var/www/laravel/public;
> index index.php index.html index.htm;
> ```
>
> server_name laravel.dev www.laravel.dev;
>
> ```
> location / {
>      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
> }
>
> location ~ \.php$ {
>     try_files $uri /index.php =404;
>     fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
>     fastcgi_index index.php;
>     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>     include fastcgi_params;
> }
>
> location ~ /\.ht {
>     deny all;
> }
> ```
>
> }

and nginx.conf:

> user www-data;
>   worker_processes 4;
>   pid /run/nginx.pid;
>
> events {
>     worker_connections  2048;
>     multi_accept on;
>     use epoll;
>   }
>
> http {
>     server_tokens off;
>     sendfile on;
>     tcp_nopush on;
>     tcp_nodelay on;
>     keepalive_timeout 15;
>     types_hash_max_size 2048;
>     client_max_body_size 20M;
>     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>     default_type application/octet-stream;
>     access_log on;
>     error_log on;
>     gzip on;
>     gzip_disable "msie6";
>     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>     include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
>     open_file_cache max=100;
>   }
>
> daemon off;

And here is my laravel's root directory's .env file:

> APP_ENV=local
>   APP_DEBUG=true
>   APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
>   APP_URL=http://localhost
>
> DB_CONNECTION=mysql
>   DB_HOST=192.168.99.100
>   DB_PORT=3306
>   DB_DATABASE=homestead
>   DB_USERNAME=homestead
>   DB_PASSWORD=secret
>
> CACHE_DRIVER=file
>   SESSION_DRIVER=file
>   QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
>
> REDIS_HOST=192.168.99.100
>   REDIS_PASSWORD=null
>   REDIS_PORT=6379
>
> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
>   MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
>   MAIL_PORT=2525
>   MAIL_USERNAME=null
>   MAIL_PASSWORD=null
>   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

I have also setup the permissions of the folder by logging into the workspace container and typing:

> chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

But still I keep getting the http 500 error on docker-machine ip. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right docker-machine ip?

Comment: Yes. I ran `docker-machine ip default` to get my IP address.

Answer (score 0):

A potential problem I see is that you use IP addresses for your service hosts (DB_HOST, REDIS_HOST) in your .env. Potentially these IP addresses can change and it is therefore safer to use the container names as host address. In your case youll want to use "DB_HOST=mysql" and "REDIS_HOST=redis".

The http 500 means there is probably nothing wrong with your nginx config and sounds more like a Laravel configuration problem. I suggest you inspect your laravel log file (`storage/logs/laravel.log`) for more information.